# About VPS Server Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, vps

can any body tell me how can i install the FFMPEG, MENCODER to my VPS server. i have WHM and cPanel.

any help about this will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run following command from SSH:

yum install mplayer mencoder

A good turorial at following URL:

http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/how-install-ffmpeg-ffmpeg-php-mplayer-mencoder-flv2tool-lame-mp3-encoder-4893/

Answer (score 0):

Install FFMPEG-PHP Extension

FFmpeg-php is a very good extension and wrapper for PHP which can pull useful information about video through API interface. Inorder to install it you will need to download the source file and then compile and install extension in your server. You can download the source tarball : http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

wget /path/to/this/file/ffmpeg-php-0.5.2.1.tbz2

tar -xjf ffmpeg-0.5.2.1.tbz2

phpize

./configure
make
make install

Answer (score 0):

A Virtual Private Server (VPS) is a type of server that allows you to run your own Linux or Unix-based server. This means that you have full control over the operating system, software, and hardware. This can be a great option if you want to set up your own server without having to deal with the hassle and expense of buying and maintaining a physical server. Additionally, with a VPS, you can share your server with other people, so they can all access it from anywhere in the world. A VPS costs more than a regular server, but the advantages justify the extra cost. You will have more control over your system and be able to customize it to your needs. Additionally, a VPS can be more reliable since it is isolated from the internet. If something goes wrong with your VPS, you will not suffer from downtime like you would if your server we're hosted on the internet.